# TFS 2010 Wont Send Email

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I can't get TFS 2010 to send email alerts. I've tried setting up everything mentioned here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-configure-tfs-notifications-in-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx

It's configured to send to a local IIS SMTP instance. SharePoint 2010 is on the same box and is also configured to use the same local SMTP server and it works fine sending emails, no problem. It's also using the same "from" email address as TFS is configured to without issue.

TFS isn't even trying to send anything as far as I can tell - I don't see anything from it in the SMTP log (C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\SMTPSVC1...).

I have the default "My Work Items changed" alert set up and enabled. I try logging in as another user, assigning a work item to me, then assigning it back...nothing happens...no email. I don't see any error in the event viewer from TFS.

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: are there any related messages in the windows event log? In my case, there was a problem concerning authentication (tfs always used anonymous when running as local network service account, else uses its domain account with windows authentication).

Comment: No, there is nothing in the event log. The TFS services are running as a dedicated domain service account that is a member of local administrators on the TFS box (I know, not best practice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had added alerts in Alert Explorer without specifying any Team Project. Once I added the Team Project filter it started working.

Comment: This worked for me.

Under Team Explorer, double-click alerts, under the "Alerts Definition" delete the existing condition, add a new condition by clicking into "Field", selecting "TeamProject", then click into the "Value" field and select your project from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try other method,

I configure the Email using Gmail Account and it is working very well, try it! if you would like? see this link for steps how you can do it?

http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/configure-tfs-2010-alert-using-local-smtp-that-use-gmail-account/

Thanks

M.Radwan

Answer (score 0):

Try this out
http://ravendra.wordpress.com/configuring-email-alert-settings-in-tfs-2010/

Or else you can go with the option of relay mail. Create a local SMTP server and relay it with the main mail server.

**Note : If you mail server requires advanced authentication then you need to follow the second option only.**

Comment: Please see the details provided in the question: It's configured to send to a local IIS SMTP instance. SharePoint 2010 is on the same box and is also configured to use the same local SMTP server and it works fine sending emails, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wanted to add this answer to give ppl an idea of what to look for when they come across 'why doesn't the email get sent out'.   The reason i came across this thread was for the same reason, it seemed that tfs wasn't sending out the email.  But it was!  the problem turned out to be the 'group' that I was sending the email to wasn't permitted to receive email.   here is the situation, TFS server located at a DATA CENTER.  The email ALERTS that i configured were to a group in our local office DOMAIN.

Apparently,in Active Directory that group didn't have the "All users need to be authenticated" checked OFF.  Meaning, the TFS server 'sender of the email' wasn't authenticated to send emails to that group.  once i sat with my MIS guys, they finally noticed that was checked on, and once DISABLED.   Problem fixed!   Hope that helps someone.